# lightning event fired or not

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

Can we check whether a lightning event of type COMPONENT was fired or not.

I have an event which is handled in parent component with 3 attributes.

Say Ocr,CI,CD..

Now what is happening is these events are fired one at a time and they are getting true or false values based on some condition.

Here when Ocr = true CD,CI are getting undefined and when CD is true Ocr,CI are undefined and CI is true Ocr,CD are undefined. So i need to check if events which are firing 3 times got fired and set some values.

FROM CONSOLE LOG (Ocr,CD,CI are for example purpose)

```
checkOcr undefined
checkCd true
checkCi undefined

checkOcr undefined
checkCd undefined
checkCi true

checkOcr true
checkCd undefined
checkCi undefined
```

So when all 3 variables become true then i need to something..I even tried using counter variable but at 2nd time it is initializing the count value again to 0.
Is it possible to check ?

Comment: Little confused here, Are you taking about three independent events here? Or same event setting 3 different attributes!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand that you have write `aura:handler` in parent component and also motioned the `action` attribute and pass a function of component controller (suppose fireEventHandlerMethod). When ever event will fire controller method will execute.

So, you have create a attribute in parent component like

```
<aura:attribute name="messageFromEvent" type="Object" default = "{Ocr : false, CI : false, CD : false}"/>
```

and in the controller method (fireEventHandlerMethod) set the value of `messageFromEvent` attribute like:

you got `Ocr = true` from event than you set true to `Ocr` of `messageFromEvent` attribute and for other also

`messageFromEvent` attribute will persist all the values and than you can do some operation on this.

Comment: Yes chandra i am doing same thing here..But as events is getting called 3 times from 3 different components each time ocr,CI,CD are getting undefined and i cannot check for 'success for all three at a time.

Comment: Like i mentioned in my Question section the values i am getting in console log

Answer (score 0):

You need to "remember" if the event was fired.

```
<aura:attribute name="ocr" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="ci" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="cd" type="Boolean" default="false" />
```

---

```
componentEventHandler: function(component, event, helper) {
  var params = event.getParams();
  if(params.ocr !== undefined) {
    component.set("v.ocr", true);
  }
  if(params.ci !== undefined) {
    component.set("v.ci", true);
  }
  if(params.cd !== undefined) {
    component.set("v.cd", true);
  }
  if(['ocr','ci','cd'].reduce((a,v) => a && component.get("v."+v), true)) {
    // all 3 are true, do something now
  }
}
```